# Number Guessing program. Too high too low issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm a very new programmer and I suck. I was trying to make a number guessing game, but I had a problem with the "Too high, Too low part." My IDE (PyCharm) kept saying `syntax error traceback line 18`. I kept tweaking that line but I'm beat. Here's the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
import random

print("Guess a number between 1 and 100. ")

randomNum = random.randint(1, 100)
found = False

while not found:
    print("Remember, you can only guess between the numbers 1-100!")

userEst = int(input("Guess here:"))
    if userEst == randomNum:
    print("You guessed right!!!")        
    found=True

if userEst > randomNum:
    print("Too high!")

if userEst < randomNum:
    print("Too low!")
```

Comment: you need to convert ingput using , int (input("Guess here:")). By default input data type is string

Comment: Oh that's it!!!! Thank you!!! Thank everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have one of those annoying indentation errors. Python gets picky about that.

```
if userEst == randomNum:
        print("You guessed right!!!")
        found=True
```

should be

```
if userEst == randomNum:
    print("You guessed right!!!")
    found=True
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I should watch little errors like that!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Also, once you're able to confirm that this fixes the problem, if you could click the little checkmark by this answer to accept it, that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm still confused why my program says"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/**myinfo:)**", line 15, in <module>
    if userEst > randomNum:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
"

Comment: After the line `userEst = input("Guess here:")` change userEst to an integer like so `userEst  = int(userEst )`. The input function gives you a string but you want an integer (a number).

Comment: Some more info on this. The computer uses the string `'5'` in the same way it uses `'a'`. Also, the computer doesn't know how to compare strings and integers, so `'a' > 3` confuses the computer. In the same way `'5' > 3` confuses the computer and it will throw an error. We have to change the `5` to a number (or an integer as programmers like to call it) by doing `int('5')`. This is what was happening to you with the TypeError you got -- strings and integers are different types and the computer got confused as to what is was suppose to do.

Comment: Wow! I'mimpressed at how devoted the programmers here are. And how nice they are. But yeah. I changed the 'userEst = input("Guess here")' to 'userEst = int(input("Guess Here"))'Thanks!

Comment: A couple more items to note. The process of changing one type to another, like a string to an integer, is called casting. So if you want to sound nerdy and cool, you could say that you're casting a string to an integer. Also, if you ever need a decimal number, use the `float()` function. `float(5)` or `float('5')` will both give you `5.0`.

Comment: I'm always happy to help out. All of us programmers know how much trouble it was for us to first learn how to program. Good luck with your programming Wes.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that in in python, the indentation is very significant. Each code block has its indentation
read more at: [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).
Thus, you need to change your code to:

```
import random

print("Guess a number between 1 and 100. ")

randomNum = random.randint(1, 100)
found = False

while not found:
    print("Remember, you can only guess between the numbers 1-100!")

    userEst = input("Guess here:")
    if userEst == randomNum:
        print("You guessed right!!!")
        found=True
    if userEst > randomNum:
        print("Too high!")

    if userEst < randomNum:
        print("Too low!")
```

By the way, you do not suck.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! I hope this works!